# Selecionar impressora ao imprimir um HierCubeChart

Tags: delphi, olap

Tenho a biblioteca *HierCube*, desta biblioteca uso um *HierCubeChart*.
Até aí sem problemas.
Mas ao mandar imprimir o gráfico por meio do comando `HierCubeChart.Print`, não consigo permitir o usuário selecionar a impressora que deverá ser impressa. Enfim quero permitir o usuário selecionar algumas configurações da impressão, ou seja, pode ser simplesmente abrir a caixa de diálogo padrão do *Windows* para impressão... mas não estou conseguindo.

Alguém usa esse componente e sabe resolver o postado acima?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um amigo do trabalho me deu uma dica que resolveu o problema:
Adicionar a *unit* ***VCLTee.TeeEdiGene***;
Ao invés de chamar o `HierCubeChart.Print`, chamar assim:

```
ChartPreview(Self,HierCubeChart);
```